# SQL AVG with Case

Tags: sql, case, average

I've a DB which stores a value from C to AAA, while C is the worst and AAA the best.

Now I need the average of this value and I don't know how to first convert the values into an int, calculate the average, round the average to an int and convert it back.

Definitions:

```
C = 1
B = 2
A = 3
AA = 4
AAA = 5
```

Is that even possible with an SQL statement? I tried to combine AVG and CASE, but I don't bring it to work...
Thanks for your help!

Regards,

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Do one thing at a time.  Start by converting the letters to their associated numbers.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select avg(case score 
             when 'C' then 1 
             when 'B' then 2
             when 'A' then 3
             when 'AA' then 4
             when 'AAA' then 5 
           end) as avg_score
from the_table;
```

(this assumes that the column is called `score`)

To convert this back into the "character value", wrap the output in another case:

```
select case cast(avg_score as int)
         when 1 then 'C'
         when 2 then 'B'
         when 3 then 'A'
         when 4 then 'AA'
         when 5 then 'AAA'
       end as avg_score_value
from (
    select avg(case score 
                 when 'C' then 1 
                 when 'B' then 2
                 when 'A' then 3
                 when 'AA' then 4
                 when 'AAA' then 5 
               end) as avg_score
    from the_table;
) t
```

The above `cast(avg_score as int)` assumes ANSI SQL. Your DBMS might have different ways to cast a value to an integer.

Comment: Many thanks! It works :-)
But the Apache Derby round the value - for example - 1.8 to 1... But I think I find a solution (with round and float) for that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've created this example for u.
u can cast ur ranking into temp table, then calculate and when ur done, drop it.

```
create table sof (id int identity,a nvarchar (10)) 
insert into sof values ('a')
insert into sof values ('b')
insert into sof values ('c')
select case a when 'AAA ' then 5
             when 'AA' then 4
             when 'A' then 3
             when 'B' then 2
             else 1
      end as av
into #temp
from sof
----for rounded
select ROUND(AVG(CAST(av AS FLOAT)), 4)
from #temp
--not rounded
select AVG (av)
from #temp
```

Comment: What is an "ur ranking"?

Comment: I thought it's a ranking column.
like AAA is the best/worse.

Comment: So what's that "ur" thing?

Comment: cuz it's not mine, it's his. :)

Comment: Sorry I don't get that. What is this "cuz" thing now?

Comment: Cousins, maybe?